# How can I skip an element of an array when I perform a .data (data) in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I would like if the data is different from USA, `d.pais`! = "USA" the data is omitted. I would like if the data is different from USA, d.pais! = "USA" the data is omitted. and that the circle is not created.

How can I do it?

```
    d3.selectAll("circle").remove();


    g.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        if(d.pais=="USA" ){
            return projection([d.longitud, d.latitud])[0];
        }
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        if(d.pais=="USA" ){
            return projection([d.longitud, d.latitud])[1];
        }
    })
    .attr("r", function(d) {
        if(d.pais=="USA" ){
         return 3;
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to filter the array of data prior to using it in your D3 logic:

```
var usaData = data.filter(d => d.pais === "USA");
g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(usaData)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
...
```

You can learn more about all the [array manipulation functions](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp) on the W3 Schools site...

Answer (score 1):

## In your scenario, you mean you want to "**filter**" the elements according to your data.

You can do **filter** on different steps in your codes. Just like @SteveR's answer, you can pre-process the data before into your d3 code with javascript array method.

Or in d3.js, it also provide some method to do filtering:

1. filtering in the **array**  [doc](https://github.com/d3/d3-array)
    
   d3.array which is inherited to javascript.Array and extended more to statistic method
2. filtering in the **element**  [doc](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_filter)
   a. use d3.selection.filter
   b. use d3.select()

## **First part**

this part is just like @SteveR's answer

```
const filtered = data.filter((d)=>{return d.location !== 'USA';})
```

## **Second part**

this part is filtering on the elements (using this approach, you will have to deal with more consideration)

### **Using the d3.selection.filter method**

```
const svg = d3.select(DOM.svg(200,200));

const circles = svg.selectAll('circle').data(data);

const circlestages = svg.selectAll('text')
                        .data(data)




circles.enter()
       .append('circle')
       .attr('cx', 10)
       .attr('cy', (d,i)=> 10 + i*20)
       .attr('r', 5)
       .attr('fill', 'red');

circlestages.enter()
            .append('text')
            .attr('x', 15)
            .attr('y', (d,i)=> 12 + i*20)
            .attr('font-size',10)
            .text((d,i)=>{
               return "name: "+ d.name +" , "+"location: " + d.location    ;
             });

 // filter after the element created
svg.selectAll('circle').filter((d,i)=> d.location === 'USA').remove();   
svg.selectAll('text').filter((d,i)=> d.location === 'USA').remove();
```

### **Using d3.select to filter the element and remove**

```
const svg = d3.select(DOM.svg(200,200));

const circles = svg.selectAll('circle').data(data);

const circlestages = svg.selectAll('text')
                        .data(data);




circles.enter()
       .append('circle')
       .attr('cx', 10)
       .attr('cy', (d,i)=> 10 + i*20)
       .attr('r', 5)
       .attr('fill', 'red');

circlestages.enter()
            .append('text')
            .attr('x', 15)
            .attr('y', (d,i)=> 12 + i*20)
            .attr('font-size',10)
            .text((d,i)=>{
              return "name: "+ d.name +" , "+"location: " + d.location ;
            })
// filter the element using d3.select()
svg.selectAll('text').select((d,i,g)=> {return d.location === 'USA'?g[i]:null}).remove();
svg.selectAll('circle').select((d,i,g)=> {return d.location === 'USA'?g[i]:null}).remove();
```

demo on Observale: https://beta.observablehq.com/@weitinglin/how-can-i-skip-an-element-of-an-array-when-i-perform-a-data-data-